# iframes wont work with wildcard catchall sub-domains and dnsmasq

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, apache, dnsmasq

I have a local development box that's setup up with apache2 and catchall wild-card sub-domains, dnsmasq and a local website. This set up is convenient for testing with multiple browsers since the web application on the local site doesn't allow multiple browsers to log in from the same location/domain.  This system works well except when I tried testing iframes and using wild-card sub-domains within the iframes src url.  After which I get a page not found error.

As evident from the URL contained within the error message that you can view at the bottom of this page, it seems that there may be some conflict between apache configuration files for virtual hosts in game and the redirect in jsgame but I'm at a loss at how to fix it.  Can anyone suggest how to fix resolve this problem?

The OS is Debian 6 and this is how my system is set up.

**Apache**

Within etc/apache2/sites-available/game

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName catchall.game
ServerAlias *.game
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1
</VirtualHost>
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mplayer.game
ServerAlias *.game
DocumentRoot /var/www/game/public
</VirtualHost>
```

**Website**

Within etc/apache2/sites_available/jsgame

```
Alias /jsgame/ usr/share/jsgame
RedirectMatch ^/jsgame/?$ /jsgame/example/index.html
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /JSGAME_REST http://127.0.0.1:19384/JSGAME_REST retry=1
ProxyPass /AVATAR http://127.0.0.1:19384/AVATAR retry=1
ProxyPass /UPLOAD http://127.0.0.1:19384/UPLOAD retry=1
```

**Dnsmasq**

line 62 within etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
# Add domains which you want to force to an IP address here.
# The example below send any host in doubleclick.net to a local
# webserver.
address=/.game/127.0.0.1
```

**index.html**

The web application is accessed via:

> master.game/jsgame/example/index.html?game_id=45

**iframe**

iframe code within /jsgame/example/index.html

```
<iframe id="player0" width="25%" height="25%" src="player0.game/jsgame/pts1.html" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0"></iframe>
```

I get this error from the iframe:

> The requested URL /jsgame/example/player0.game/pts1.html was not found on this server.

**I expected that the URL would be:**

> player0.game/example/pts1.html not as shown above.

Comment: What if you use `http://player0.game/example/pts1.html` instead? It would avoid being considered relative.

Comment: @ YoannM, In your solution, What actually causes the URL to be considered relative or not?

Comment: It was essentially a guess, but with `http://` you're absolutely sure it's absolute. I can't test your setup for the moment, so I can't efficiently help you. Sorry.

Comment: You were correct, I wasn't aware that http:// would make a difference.  When I read your solution I thought only that you meant to add the directory /example and didn't add the http://.  I tried again today and it worked.  I wanted to give you credit. If you post the answer i'll select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you use `http://player0.game/jsgame/pts1.html` instead of `player0.game/jsgame/pts1.html` as the `src` attribute of your iframe?

```
<iframe 
   id="player0" 
   width="25%" 
   height="25%" 
   src="http://player0.game/jsgame/pts1.html" 
   style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0">
</iframe>
```

It would avoid being considered relative.

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved me a ton of grief!

Comment: No problem at all. I'm happy that my wild guess was the correct answer :)